# Missing vertical line in longtable

Tags: tables

I'm missing the vertical line at the right! What can I do?

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % Uncomment for 1.5 spacing between lines
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref} % use for hypertext links, including those to external documents and URLs

\renewcommand{\deg}{$^{\circ}$}

\newcommand{\eg}{\emph{e.g. }}
\newcommand{\ie}{\emph{i.e. }}
\newcommand{\Eg}{\emph{E.g. }}
\newcommand{\Ie}{\emph{I.e. }}
\newcommand{\cf}{\emph{c.f. }}
\newcommand{\Cf}{\emph{C.f. }}
\captionsetup{width=.8\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|p{80mm}} 

\caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Feasible triples for 
highly variable Grid, MLMMH.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Kommun}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Klimatanpassning}}  \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{c} 
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Kommun}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Klimatanpassning}}  \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot


Arboga & \vspace{-5mm}\begin{itemize}
\item daf
\item  asdf
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize} \\ \hline
Fagersta &  \vspace{-5mm}\begin{itemize}
\item ad
\item  df
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize}.\\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a `| ` after the `p{80mm}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you beat me to it - over 10 minutes must have gone by while I was testing.  I guess I should delete my answer, but leaving no answer doesn't seem right either.

Comment: Consider not to use vertical lines. Tables look better without them. Use package `booktabs` to insert horizontal rules if needed.

Comment: Vertical lines should be avoided in tables; they disturb the viewer more than they help in interpretating the data. (Next time, please make your [example minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).)

Answer (score 3):

As said in my comment it is better not to use vertical lines.

Please compare the following two tables. I used your MWE and added the second table. I deleted some code in your MWE not needed for your problem and I did some pretty printing ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref} 


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|p{80mm}|} 

\caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Feasible triples for 
highly variable Grid, MLMMH.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Kommun}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Klimatanpassning}}  \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{c} 
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Kommun}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Klimatanpassning}}  \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

Arboga & \vspace{-5mm}\begin{itemize}
\item daf
\item  asdf
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize} \\ \hline
Fagersta &  \vspace{-5mm}\begin{itemize}
\item ad
\item  df
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize}.\\ \hline

\end{longtable}

compare with:

\rowcolors[]{2}{white}{blue!15} 
\begin{longtable}{lp{80mm}} 
  \caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Feasible triples for highly variable Grid, MLMMH.}%
  \label{tab:test} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Kommun}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Klimatanpassning}}  \\ 
\midrule 
\endfirsthead

%\multicolumn{2}{c} {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Kommun}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Klimatanpassning}}  \\ 
\midrule 
\endhead

\midrule 
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
\bottomrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


Arboga & \vspace{-5mm}
\begin{itemize}
  \item daf
  \item  asdf
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize} 
\\ 

Fagersta &  \vspace{-5mm}
\begin{itemize}
  \item ad
  \item  df
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize}.\\ 

Fagersta &  \vspace{-5mm}
\begin{itemize}
  \item ad
  \item  df
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize}.\\ 

Fagersta &  \vspace{-5mm}
\begin{itemize}
  \item ad
  \item  df
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize}.\\ 

Fagersta &  \vspace{-5mm}
\begin{itemize}
  \item ad
  \item  df
\vspace{-5mm}\end{itemize}.\\ 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the right vertical line specifier in your longtable command - try:
`\begin{longtable}{|l|p{80mm}|}`